# Routing/Resolving asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a question that I have been thinking about.

What happens from when I enter an URL in my browser and click enter to when the code in the corresponding controller actually executes?

Let's say I have an asp.net mvc application and a trivial Controller like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult About(int id = 25)
  {
    //code
  }
}
```

So if I enter like `myUrl/home/about?id=56` that controller gets invoked. I know there is a routing pattern like `{controller}/{action}/{id}` declared by default. But if an URL matches that pattern is a controller instance created then or what happens? Is there some Resolver class or similar? Is there like a List containing all the controllers so "Home" in the URL matches the `HomeController`?

I know the id parameter in the controller signature will be bound to the corresponding id value in the request context with the help of model binding. But there must be a lot of other magic happening here.

Hope someone can help a fresh confused asp.net mvc user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in a nutshell:

1. `DefaultControllerFactory` finds and instantiates the controller by its name using reflection ([more info](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Inside-the-ASP-NET-MVC-Controller-Factory.aspx))
2. `ControllerActionInvoker` finds and invokes the action by its name using reflection  ([more info](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx))

Good overall description can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd695917.aspx).